# Extending Django-Admin Login (username, password, sites)

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to extend Django Admin Login. Most of the resources pointed towards extending views after the Login.

I wanted to add sites to the Login criteria.

So instead of

- Username
- Password

It will be

- Username
- Password
- Site

Such that the Site will check whether the user belongs to the Site as admin and if it is, it will load only data belongs to the site.

Thanks

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because I am newbee in django.

I would copy the admin code from the original django code in my profject folder. Then I would change it like you want it and put it in installed apps.

I hope, I could help you. As I said, I am a newbee in django.

Craphunter

Answer (score 0):

You use [user profiles](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) for this.

Here's a basic example (this code would go in your app's `models.py`):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Define a signal handler to be called after saving
# a User object
def user_save_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    # If the save was creating a new user as opposed
    # to updating an existing one, then create a 
    # UserProfile object and associate it with the User
    if kwargs['created']:
        # kwargs['instance'] is the User object we just
        # created
        UserProfile(user=kwargs['instance']).save()

# Hook the signal handler up to the User model's post_save
# signal
post_save.connect(user_save_handler, sender=User)

# Define your UserProfile class as usual. 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # user is a one-to-one reference to the associated
    # User object. You need this field
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Now define any other fields you care about
    birthday = models.DateField()
```